# DataBase Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

So, I am creating this movie quiz app for my project and I am having difficulty figuring out queries for it. I would appreciate if you could help me out.

so, schema looks like following. 
table 1: movies 
values - id (primary key) title, year, director, movies

table 2: stars
values - id (primary key) first_name, last_name

table 3: stars_in_movie 
values - star_id, movie_id

and following are the questions for which I need to find queries for.

```
Who directed the movie X? I figuered this one out.
```

select first_name,last_name from stars_in_movies inner join stars where movie_id=%s and star_id=id;

```
Who directed the star X?
Who did not directed the star X?
Which star appears in both movies X and Y?
Which star did not appear in the same movie with the star X?
Who directed the star X in year Y?
```

I would appreciate your help. 
Thank you.

Comment: you'll need to learn SQL if you wish to use it.

Comment: I know SQL but I am kinda bummed out on this one. Needed your help, not your advice

Answer (score 0):

While you may have to take care of mysql syntax, here are the broad hints. You can use inner joins as per mysql syntax instead of IN to accomplish this more effectively.

```
select director from movies where movieid in (select movieid from star_in_movie where starid in (select starid from stars where first_name like ....  ))

select director from movies where movieid NOT in (select movieid from star_in_movie where starid in (select starid from stars where first_name like ....  ))

select first_name, last_name from stars where (starid in (select starid from star_in_movie where movieid in (select movieid from movies where title = X)))
And 
(starid in (select starid from star_in_movie where movieid in (select movieid from movies where title = X)))
```

I'll leave the other two to your imagination based on the hints above. Let me know if you still need help with those. The syntax for inner join in mysql must be like : X inner join Y on X.colname = Y.colname.